# Creating a data dump using RDFib and adding data to a Graph without iteration

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, linked-data, rdflib

I have parsed some data from DBpedia using RDFlib:

```
dbpediaSparqlEndpoint = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql/'
sparql = SPARQLWrapper(dbpediaSparqlEndpoint)
dbpedia_query = 'PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {{?s ?p ?o FILTER (?s=:Benin)} UNION {?s ?p ?o . FILTER (?o=:Benin)}}'
dataGraph = Graph()

sparql.setQuery(dbpedia_query)
sparql.method = 'GET'
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
output = sparql.query().convert()
```

I'd like to create a dump file that I can then use to upload to a triple store. These are the steps I think I need to take now:

1. Add the output data into a graph
2. Use `output.serialize(destination="dbpediaDump.txt", format='turtle')` to generate the dump

Is this the most efficient approach? Also, is there a shortcut to add all the data from output to a graph at once instead of iterating through the list and adding triples one by one?

Comment: Note that the [DBpedia limits](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vyzaG_p7xAXcu5ocpwcmPyy3k1xi_udFSofqIzaTMdY/) have and will change over time. Alternatively to the `LIMIT/OFFSET` path, you can [run your own DBpedia instance](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), without the protections that are implemented on the public endpoint. ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/); we make [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), the engine that hosts DBpedia, and the AMI I'm pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

DBpedia SPARQL results are limited in number, meaning that in order to obtain all the requested results is often necessary to reiterate the query using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` constrains. Moreover, DBpedia availability is not guaranteed and errors have to be taken into account.

The most efficient way to load rdf data into a private graph-db is using a service like [LinkedData.Center](http://LinkedData.Center) with this configuration:

```
@PREFIX <http://linkeddata.center/kees/v1#> .

[]  a kees:SparqlIngestion
    kees:queryName <http://mydata.example.com/resource/Benin> ;
    kees:sparqlEndpoint <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>  ;
    kees:constructQuery """
        PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
        CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o} 
        WHERE {{?s ?p ?o FILTER (?s=:Benin)} UNION {?s ?p ?o . FILTER (?o=:Benin)}}
    """ 
.
```

The complete documentation of the used ingestion APIs is available [here](http://linkeddata.center/help/devop/kees-profile)

disclaimer: I'm a LinkedData.Center intern

Comment: I'm trying to ensure I understood you correctly. 1. Using OFFSET and LIMIT entails running the query multiple times and then concatenating the output from each query. Is that what you meant? 2. Are there any thresholds till which DBpedia doesn't restrict the number of results? In my query, the result set is expected to be limited.

Comment: In order to prevent unfair usage DBpedia has both rate limiting on the  number of connections/sec you can make, as well as restrictions on  resultset and query time (see [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-lod/2011Aug/0028.html)). So you can't retrieve more than 2000 rows per query. If you expect to have more than 2k results you have to run your query multiple times and then concatenating the output as you say.